# SweetAlert with Angular 7

Tags: angular, sweetalert

I am trying to use sweet alert in my angular project.

That's how I use sweet alert:

```
import swal from 'sweetalert';

swal({
    title: "Problem",
    text: "Try again later!",
    icon: "error"
  })
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR in node_modules/sweetalert/typings/sweetalert.d.ts(4,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'swal' must be of type 'typeof import("C:/Users/user/Desktop/University/Thesis/workspace/web/myProject/project/node_modules/sweetalert/typings/sweetalert")', but here has type 'SweetAlert'.

Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: can you add full code

Comment: Seems to work just fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t7omte.
Can you reproduce the issue in stackblitz?

Comment: Check your package.json and make sure you're using the right sweet alert dependency. I've been using this one "sweetalert": "^2.1.2" without issues.

Comment: Thank you guys. The solution was to change typescript version. Not sure why but worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, my solution was this.

```
import * as _swal from 'sweetalert';
import { SweetAlert } from 'sweetalert/typings/core';

const swal: SweetAlert = _swal as any;
```

for some reason the name "swal" show error, if you change alias by "_swal" it should work

Comment: Where did make this change?

Comment: at the top of the file, for example when i need to use the sweetalert on a particular component or service.

Comment: `import * as _swal from 'sweetalert';
import { SweetAlert } from 'sweetalert/typings/core'; `
export class MyComponent {
...
`updateHospital(hospital: Hospital) {
    let url = URL_SERVICE + '/hospital/' + hospital._id;
    url += `?token=${this._userService.token}`;
    const swal: SweetAlert = _swal as any;

    return this.http.put(url, hospital).pipe(map((res:any) => {
      swal('updated', hospital.name, 'success');
      return res.hospital;
    }));
  }`

Answer (score 12):

The simple solution to compile the Angular project is 
Go to your project folder
\node_modules\sweetalert\typings\sweetalert.d.ts

In this file simply comment the line 
// const swal: SweetAlert;

and your final file looks like this:

```js
import swal, { SweetAlert } from "./core";

declare global {
  // const swal: SweetAlert;
  const sweetAlert: SweetAlert;
}

export default swal;
export as namespace swal;
```

Comment: for me too :D, it was an issue with Vue.js  but works :D

Comment: It will not solve the problem in the case you delete the node_modules folder and then ```npm i```. You could make a little script that runs before every build to comment that line out, but it would be great if the developers would do that.

Answer (score 1):

It's solved with me when i remove simple line of code existing in :

```
node_modules/sweetalert/src/sweetalert.d.ts
```

Code will be look like this :

```
import swal, { SweetAlert } from "./core";

declare global {
  const swal: SweetAlert;
  const sweetAlert: SweetAlert;
}

export default swal;
export as namespace swal;
```

Just remove this line : `const swal: SweetAlert;`

And you can check this on gitgub : https://github.com/AlbinoDrought/sweetalert-sans-ts-namespace/commit/699f10b8546a524000dd3e3b41bf7a7e599a2666

Answer (score 0):

For SweetAlert2 you just should to use this line to import it:

```
import * as Swal from 'sweetalert2';
```

then use it this way:

```
Swal.fire('Hello world!');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got no idea what I just did, but apparently, that's what the compiler wanted me to do cause it worked when I had your same problem:

In the file "/node_modules/sweetalert/typings/sweetalert.d.ts", replace the type of swal in the line
"swal: SweetAlert" with "swal: typeof swal"

So, this (before):

```
import swal, { SweetAlert } from "./core";

declare global {
const swal: SweetAlert;
const sweetAlert: SweetAlert;
}

export default swal;
export as namespace swal;
```

becomes this (after):

```
import swal, { SweetAlert } from "./core";

declare global {
const swal: typeof swal;
const sweetAlert: SweetAlert;
}

export default swal;
export as namespace swal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'; 

Swal.fire('Error', 'Please Enter Username', 'error');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem it was due to the way I imported sweetalert
it is necessary to put
const swal = require('sweetalert');
INSTEAD OF
import swal from 'sweetalert';

Answer (score -2):

BEFORE ALL.. I'm recently update node_modules... and some issues appeared. The last of those, was this one!

I tried with  `npm install sweetalert2`....
but the still giving me problems... 
so the final solution was....
eliminate that line and WORKS FINE, WITHOUT ERRORS..!